# Google spreadsheets - negative number to zero

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, negative-number

I am using following formula in Google spreadsheets =K69*0,09
I need to show a result only as a positive number. I need to set negative numbers to zero. Max function does not work. How else can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

`=max(0;C4*0,09)` works fine here. But when you cannot use MAX, use :

`=if(C4<0;0;C4*0,09)`

Comment: Used MAX the way you advised and it works. I must have used it in a wrong way before. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
=IF(K69*0,09<0; 0; K69*0,09)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent method, if query too big:

`ARRAYFORMULA( IF(A:A="some value"; ARRAYFORMULA( LAMBDA( array; if(array<0; 0; array)) (any result from B:B if A:A="some value") ); C) )`